# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'(Angular)

Tags: angular, rest

I've got the error in the title when I created this program. I try to get some info from an REST API using Angular. I attached the service, the ts from the component and the html. I use rxjs and Observable for this. I inject the service in the constructor.  I will appreciate any help. Thank you!
[image: console]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HeroService } from './services/hero.service';
import {Customer} from './models/customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.scss']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  private ndg: string;
  public customerData;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {
     this.ndg='117158101';
   }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.heroService.getCustomerInfo(this.ndg)
        .subscribe(data => { this.customerData=data,
          console.log(this.customerData)
        }, error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

```css
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../../services/base.services';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../../../../environments/environment';
import {Customer} from '../models/customer';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  getCustomerInfo(ndg: string) {
    const url = `${environment.apiUrl}${environment.ur3Path}cifCustomerDetails/customers/${ndg}`;
    return this.apiService.get(url);
  }
}
```

```html
<!--
 --   Hero component
-->

<section class="hero">
  <div class="content-hero" *ngFor="let customer of customerData">
    <h1>Welcome to your loan <br/> application, {{customer.name}}</h1>
    <h4>Your RM today is Sandra Menter.</h4>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `console.log(this.customerData)`?

Comment: Or try: `public customerData: any[] = []`

Comment: Most likely `this.customerData` is not an array, but an object. You should have something like `let customer of customerData.xxx` where `xxx` is the name of the array you can see in the `customerData`

Comment: Show the console's logged data!

Comment: {rCode: 0, customer: {…}}
customer:
emails: [{…}]
name: "Yobfh"
surname: "Yqbxiy"
__proto__: Object
rCode: 0
__proto__: Object

Comment: I would like to show the name and the surname

Comment: @AndreiGhervan Can you add that in the question `valid and well formatted JSON` Or post the image of console.log

Comment: ok. I will add it!

Comment: I added the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngFor` is a construct used to replicate the tag for multiple elements, like if you have an array of customers. In your case, there is no need to use it, it should be as simple as:

```
<section class="hero">
  <div class="content-hero">
    <h1>Welcome to your loan <br/> application, {{customerData.customer.name}}</h1>
    <h4>Your RM today is Sandra Menter.</h4>
  </div>
</section>
```